# Pillbox probability problem

Tags: probability

For older adults and drug-dependent people, weekly pillboxes can be a great support and solution to organize their medication in a simple and practical way, allowing to avoid gaps and errors in medication. Suppose that a person prepares the weekly pillbox on Sunday by entering  each day the three pills that he must take at night before going to sleep.Today, Wednesday morning, he dropped the pillbox from his hands. When he picked them up, since they were the same size and color, it was not possible to distinguish the three different pills, so he took three randomly and left them in the Wednesday compartment, another three in Thursday's compartment, and so on. What is the probability that he has no errors in his medication today?

I tried multinomial coefficient, but I'm not sure if you can do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The Wednesday compartment now houses a random sample of three pills from a set of $15$, $5$ of each type. The probability that the chosen pills are correct, with one of each type, is given by a hypergeometric distribution:
$$p=\frac{\binom51^3}{\binom{15}3}=\frac{25}{182}$$